# Email Sent But Not Receiving with swiftMailer

Tags: symfony, email, send, swiftmailer

I am facing issue in Symfony Swiftmailer to send mail.

By Using command:

php app/console swiftmailer:email:send

and  this  is  my  swiftMailer.yaml

swiftmailer:

```
transport:            gmail
username:             "**************@*******"
password:             "****************"
host:                 smtp.gmail.com
port:                 465
encryption:           ~
auth_mode:            ~
sender_address:       ~
antiflood:
    threshold:            99
    sleep:                0
delivery_addresses:   ~
disable_delivery:     ~
logging:              true
```

is  there  anyone know  what is the problem ?

Comment: I tried it  and  it  return                                                                                                                    ([2018-01-23 09:44:43] Processing default mailer spool...
 1 emails sent     )                                                                                                                        but no mail received

Comment: Then if you login into gmail can you see the email in the Sent Mail folder?

Comment: I checked and I  have not received anything

Comment: I said `Sent Mail` not `Inbox` :)

Comment: Also you run the command without passing env, which means dev is used iirc. Maybe in your dev configuration you have `disable_delivery` enabled? Or `delivery_address` set to a different one? You should update question with more code/configs.

Comment: I checked and no mail sent in the sent Mail Folder

Comment: I tried  to  change  swiftmailer.yaml  and disable_delivery enabled  but I have  not  received anything

Answer (score 1):

If your Gmail account uses 2-Step-Verification, you must [generate an App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) and use it as the value of the mailer password. You must also ensure that you [allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).

Comment: I checked and both are well configured